# Boolean-Integer Typecasting to Replace Conditional

Tags: readability, data-types, conditions, type-casting

When choosing a value based off of 2 boolean values in this format

```
var foo:int;

if (X){
    foo = 50;
} else if (Y){
    foo = -50;
} else {
    foo = 0;
}
```

I discovered that I can condense this down by typecasting the boolean operations to integers,  and mathing it up a bit like so:

```
var foo:int;

foo = ( int (X) - int(!X && Y) ) * 50;
// int() typecasts a boolean argument to an int of 1 if true, 0 if false.
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is this approach less resource intensive?
2. Is this approach readable to you?
3. Is assigning values in this way common?
4. If 1 is true then in your opinion, does the performance increase justify the less readable nature of this approach?

This situation arose in ActionScript 3.0, but I am interested in answers from all languages, and from a best practice perspective.

Comment: "i am interested in answers from all languages" – I don't even know any programming language that would allow such a horrible thing.

Comment: The second approach, when I see it in code I am maintaining, is the kind that makes it quite likely I will become the psychopathic mass murderer, who will find out where you live, that your tutor should have warned you about.

Comment: I'm self taught, so i'm really not sure what would be readable to other people.

Comment: I've learnt quite a bit since posting this and for the love of god please don't use this. Children will spit at your feet as you walk past them for enacting such a travesty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is to some extent a matter of style, but I really believe your single-line option is much, much less readable, and is not a common approach.

The first classic `if` is very easy to read and check. There's no complex nesting, just a plain, "boring", chain of conditions that is well understood in all languages that have an `if/else if/else` construct.

The second is very tricky:

- Two conditionals, one of them a composite for which you need to know operator precedence
  (is `!X && Y` interpreted as `(!X) && Y` or `!(X && Y)`)
- Two casts for which you need to know that `true` is converted to `1` and `false` to `0` (or are those function calls?). This might be common, but it's something people aren't always aware of, or aware that the language guarantees that. (That is if you're indeed using a built-in cast in this example - if it's a custom function call, then that needs to be known too)
- Then you have to figure out what the result of that `-` operation will be in what circumstances. Pretty basic maths, but needs a few brain cycles more than the trivial `if/else` cascade.

As for the second version could somehow be more efficient? I don't think so. In fact, it might be not only less efficient, but not behave the same way as the first. `X` is evaluated twice (so potentially more expensive). If the evaluation of `X` has side-effects, the two versions aren't equivalent.

(And let's not mention C-type macros that could break the second version while the first works, or the issues with un-sequenced operations your second version could entail in C and C++ because of that double evaluation in a single statement - I don't think that's the point of your question here.)

**tl;dr**: less lines of code does not mean more efficient. Your code should be written so that it can be efficiently *maintained*. Your compiler/runtime/interpreter will take care of the dirty work of optimizing as long as you've chosen the right algorithms and data structures and expressed them clearly in your language.

Comment: Thank you, i knew that the if/else chain was the more readable approach, but i was unsure of which was more efficient, and i hadn't thought of the ramifications of the double X evaluation or operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this approach less resource intensive?

I wrote two simple bits of C and looked at the dissassembly of each.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char x = argv[1][0] == 't';
    char y = argv[1][1] == 't';
    int foo;

    if(x) {
        foo = 50;
    } else if (y) {
        foo = -50;
    } else {
        foo = 0;
    }

    printf("%d",foo);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char x = argv[1][0] == 't';
    char y = argv[1][1] == 't';
    int foo = ( x - (!x && y) ) * 50;

    printf("%d",foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Pardon my dissasemblines, I'm on a mac rather than a linux box and so I don't have easy access to `gcc -S` so I'm not going to paste them here.  When looking at the sequence of events in each that is the if statements or the expression:

This sequence in the first is:
`cmpb je movl jmp cmpb je movl jmp movl jmp leaq movl movb`
The same reigon in the second version is:
`movsbl cmpb movl movb jne movsbl cmpl setne movb movb leaq andb movzbl movl subl imull movl movl movb`

The first you can see the compare, jump equal, assign, jump to end, compare, jump equal, assign, jump to end, assign.  IN the second, there is a significant amount of operations being done.  One can see the `andb`, `subl` and `imull` doing arithmetic operators.

The first will do a small number of comparisons to constants and branches.  The second does a significant number of operations.

> Is this approach readable to you?

The first is by far more readable and maintainable.  Even if the second was to produce more optimal code, I would still write the first as the fractions of a second that are saved in the code are lost many times over when someone comes back to maintain the code and goes WTF?!

> Is assigning values in this way common?

No.  I have never seen it before this situation.

> If 1 is true then in your opinion, does the performance increase
>   justify the less readable nature of this approach?

As I mentioned, the maintainability of the code is paramount in any situation where someone else may ever have the joys of touching your code later.

As a perl programmer, I recognize the value of hubris:

> Hurbis: Excessive pride, the sort of thing Zeus zaps you for. Also the quality
>   that makes you write (and maintain) programs that other people won't
>   want to say bad things about. Hence, the third great virtue of a
>   programmer.

I know I would say bad things about a programmer that writes the second, so I'm not about to do so.

Comment: thank you for your response. i am not advocating the second method, i just stumbled upon it and didn't think i'd seen it before anywhere else so i wanted others thoughts on it, i should have realized that it's not good practice from the fat that i hadn't seen it elsewhere.